# Is it acceptable to run 22/4 security wire along side Cat6 and Coax cables, or is there any possibility for interference?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ethernet, alarm, interference

Security wire is connected to motion/vibration/magnetic sensors and alarm keypad.

Can it disrupt the alarm system? or cause speed/performance loss in the cat 6 transmissions?

Answer (score 5):

No cause for concern, cat 6 and other UTP network cables are very good at rejecting interference, the relatively low voltage and power of the security system will not disrupt the signal on the UTP.  Big, high power sources of interference like arc welders might.

Comment: Can the cat6 disrupt the security wires?

Comment: No, even less likely.